# Mass CSS adaptation to IE 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I've got 5k lines of CSS for Firefox, Opera and sometimes IE 8. After all that, account told me, that it has to work properly under IE 7. How can I do it, without rewriting 40% of code?

Answer (score 3):

After going through and fixing the glaringly obvious problems, try this: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

It isn't a magic bullet, and it may cause problems. Personally, I just accept that ie-izing a site will take time, and factor that time into reports I am required to make to bosses.

If you start with IE8 and get your site working in that, it'll be easier to go down to IE7, which will make it easier to go down to IE6. Note that IE8 has some debugging tools that don't completely suck, be thankful for those.

http://websitetips.com/css/solutions/

http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/internet-explorer.shtml

http://css-tricks.com/ie-css-bugs-thatll-get-you-every-time/

Comment: Is it safe to use this with jQuery on the same site? Also, +1 for "just accept that ie-izing a site will take time" :)

Comment: I don't know, we use Prototype. Our site is so JS heavy that I just bit the bullet and went through and fixed all IE CSS problems we could find instead of throwing more JS onto the pile.

Comment: Actually the same developer tool (IE developer toolbar) are also available for older version, with approximately similar capabilities. jQuery should also be safe to use. Microsoft also claims IE8 to be fully CSS 2.1 compliant, so it won't have the same bugs as IE7.

Comment: Microsoft makes a lot of claims.

Comment: Well yes, but as far as I'm aware there's only one very weird `noscript` bug, but other than that IE8 is clear. http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/ie8stylednoscriptbug/index.html